# Requesting a ShowcaseView example

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, nineoldandroids, showcaseview

I've been hearing a lot about Espiandev [ShowcaseView](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=showcaseview) as a good tutorial tool for Android apps, but unfortunately I couldn't find any examples of its implementation but the sample provided with the library. No matter what I tried, **I could not get that sample to compile**. I've installed the library and its dependencies on my Eclipse IDE as instructed [here](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView) and it looks like it was installed fine. Eclipse tells me to import R (android) on both java files (`SampleActivity` and `ActionItemsSampleActivity`) and none of the usual tricks work (like cleaning the project, for example). Also, it doesn't know what StrictMode is. The Styles.xml also gives out compilation errors such as `No resource found that matches the name: attr 'text'` and also for `showcaseButtonStyle`. I am also using ActionBarSherlock in my workspace.

Please, can someone provide a working example or point me to a step-by-step tutorial (or YouTube)?

Comment: Having taken a look at this, I think there is an issue where IntelliJ (which I use) accepts things which Eclipse doesn't. I'm taking a look at it now and will report back!

Comment: Can you try using the latest on Github? You will probably need to add the library as a dependency to the sample project.

Comment: I got the latest and got the sample to work. Thanks! Can you provide a sample that would work with a SherlockFragment? It doesn't work for my SherlockFragment where I have a GridView with many ImageView objects (The exception it throws is that `sv` is `null` after `insertShowcaseView`). I tried replacing parameters, casting, and finally modifying your library but nothing worked.

Comment: sure; please open an issue on the Github project detailing the error (including some code to replicate it) and I'll take a look

Comment: Thank you very much for taking a look. https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView/issues/39